# Clear copied dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Recently i created a post about clearing dictionary formed like key->value(NSArray).

I have 2 NSDictionary, first with data, second should contain all keys from first, but empty data for that key. Data will be added/removed later. This is how i create copy from main data dict (self.viewModel.releaseDict):

```
_releaseFormsDictCopy = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.viewModel.releaseDict];
```

When i checked, that objects (2 NSDictionaries) have different memory.

However, when i "clear" copy with method:

```
-(void)clearAllArraysInsideKeys{

    for(id key in self) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [self objectForKey:key];
        [arr removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

It appears that it flush all data from both dictionaries, not only copy. How to prevent clearing first NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionaries may be different instances, but their contents are still the same instances - you have created a shallow (mutable) copy. From your description what you want is a deep copy, where the dictionaries are different instances and each of the arrays they contain as the values are also different instances.

Simple option is to deep copy only that level. Create an empty `NSMutableDictionary` and then enumerate `self.viewModel.releaseDict` and add each key with a `mutableCopy` of the value.

This will be a 'deep-ish' copy of the dictionary, containing a 'shallow' copy of each array it contains.

Comment: i guess that will work, thanks. I tried to did simplier solution -    NSArray *arr = @[];
    _releaseFormsDictCopy = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arr forKeys:_sectionsArray];, however, it throw a exception. What i did wrong here?

Comment: you created an immutable array, so i guess sometime later you try to use it as mutable ?

Comment: no, it throw exception on that line.NSArray *arr = @[]; _releaseFormsDictCopy = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arr forKeys:_sectionsArray];,

Comment: oh, i see, you're giving it an empty list of values for a non-empty list of keys, you can't do that...

Comment: hm, not realy empty, an array with nil objects, is that forbidden to have empty array for specific key?

Comment: it finally work with  for(id key in self.viewModel.releaseDict) {
        NSMutableArray* mutArr = [NSMutableArray new];
        mutArr = [[self.viewModel.releaseDict objectForKey:key] mutableCopy];
        [mutArr removeAllObjects];
        [_releaseFormsDictCopy setObject:[mutArr mutableCopy] forKey:key];
    }